# Gets function is overleaped

Tags: c, scanf, gets

```
typedef struct
{
    char podrucje[32];
    char opis[128]; 
}kvar;

typedef struct
{
    char ime_podnosioca[16];
    char prezime_podnosioca[16];
    kvar k;
    int popravljeno;
}prijava;
 void main()
{
   prijava prijave;
   printf("Unesite ime i prezime podnosioca:\n");
   scanf("%s%s",prijave.ime_podnosioca, prijave.prezime_podnosioca);    
   printf("Unesite podrucje koje obuhvata kvar:\n::>");
    gets(prijave.k.podrucje);
    printf("Unesite opis kvara:\n::>");
    gets(prijave.k.opis);
}
```

After I debug application I get this error, here is screenshot: http://www56.zippyshare.com/v/83042434/file.html

Comment: You use a function (`gets`) which is obsolete and known to cause problems and you wonder why you are having problems?  What exactly is your question?

Comment: Its a bad idea to use `void main()`,`gets()` etc. I know you are desperately waiting for a solution. Just add a `getchar()` after the `scanf()` and the problem will be gone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points should be noted:

- `gets` is an evil and no longer exist in standard C. Use `fgets` instead.
- You should be careful when using `scanf` and `fgets` together because `scanf` leaves `\n` character in the buffer for next call of input read function. This `\n` is read by `fgets` after the `scanf` function.

Answer (score 0):

I have added one more gets, and now it works.

```
 typedef struct
    {
        char podrucje[32];
        char opis[128]; 
    }kvar;

    typedef struct
    {
        char ime_podnosioca[16];
        char prezime_podnosioca[16];
        kvar k;
        int popravljeno;
    }prijava;
     void main()
    {
       prijava prijave;
       printf("Unesite ime i prezime podnosioca:\n");
       scanf("%s%s",prijave.ime_podnosioca, prijave.prezime_podnosioca);    
       printf("Unesite podrucje koje obuhvata kvar:\n::>");
        gets(prijave.k.podrucje);
        **gets(prijave.k.podrucje);**
        printf("Unesite opis kvara:\n::>");
        gets(prijave.k.opis);
    }
```